# Drop , crop and resize images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop an image to image holder divs of different shapes. While dropping, it should crop it according to the div shape (without user interaction on cropping). The divs should be rotatable or movable too with the dropped image. How can i do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/vAN6e/embedded/result/

Comment: Derek & gideon: i have modified this to drop images in slots: http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/. It works fine. i'm actually looking for cropping functionlity when dropping images and rotating slots with dropped images. Rotating in the sense, user can rotate by dragging from mouse.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the scope of jquery.

To crop images or div to different sharps, you need HTML5 or SVG or RIA. (Css3 can also help you do some simple work like rotate.)

If you just want a drag-drop function, suggest you look at [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)